Is it practical to paint Liquid-tight Flexible Non-metallic Conduit (LFNC)?
I'm installing about 70-100 feet of 1/2" or 3/4" LFNC on sand-colored exterior siding, most exposed to direct California sun. Apparently, the LFNC used to be available in white or light color, but is now just medium gray or black.
I would both like to minimize the visual impact of the conduit and help protect it against UV, so was thinking of painting it. First clean with alcohol, then prime with Zinsser 1-2-3, then paint with Rustoleum light almond enamel.
Is this practical? Will the paint flake off during conduit installation?
